# Cursor style changed in Unity after installing Sugar DE

Tags: unity, mouse-pointer

I have been testing different desktop environments on my Ubuntu 14.04, and have at several occasions experienced that themes, splash screens etc. have changed. (In addition to a lot of new software, of course.) That has mostly not been a problem, as the changes has never been that important to me, or they where easy to roll back.

However, after installing the [Sugar](https://www.sugarlabs.org/) desktop environment, my cursor in Unity has changed to the sugar look. Is there an easy way to change the cursor back, preferably without changing it in sugar too?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. In case anybody else experiences the same problem, you can change the cursor look with these steps:

- Run "Customize look and feel" (search for it in the menu).
- Click on "Mouse cursor".

Here, you can chose between a lot of options, including the one you perhaps got stuck with after the installation of an additional DE.